# "Run selection" and "Source" give different results when runnning R scripts containing Chinese

Tags: r, dplyr, cjk

The following codes give different results in Rstudio when "run selection" and "source"

```
library(dplyr)
gender <- c("女", "女", "女", "男", "男", "男")
gender2 <- recode(gender, "男"="M", "女"="F")
print(gender2)
```

Running selection (Ctrl+Enter) correctly recode gender from Chinese to alphabet, while source the script does not recode the vector. I was running the script in Windows 10.

Comment: Not positive, but dplyr really is for data frames and windows data frames do not support utf-8.   What do you get when you source? Is gender2 the same as gender?

Comment: @Elin When I source, I get c("M","M","M","M","M", "M”) for gender2.

Comment: Please add that to your question. Also normally you should use `library(dplyr)`.  When you do run selection are you highlighting the whole thing?

Comment: I'm getting the same for both but that is on mac.  I edited your code slightly -- try running it that way.